# TLE in SPOJ ABCDEF

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, brute-force

I am trying to solve [ABCDEF](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABCDEF/) using java, but I am keep getting the Time Limit Exceeded (TLE). Can any one suggest me how should I make it more efficient .

The Question is as follows:

You are given a set S of integers between -30000 and 30000 (inclusive).

Find the total number of sextuples (a,b,c,d,e,f) which belongs to set S so that it satisfy the equation:

**a*b + c = (f+e)d**

Input

The first line contains integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), the size of a set S.

Elements of S are given in the next N lines, one integer per line. Given numbers will be distinct.

Output

Output the total number of plausible sextuples.

My Solution was

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //a*b + c = (f+e)d
    // -30000 and 30000 d!=0

    Reader in = new Reader();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);


    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    List<Long> lhs = new ArrayList<Long>(n * n * n);
    List<Long> rhs = new ArrayList<Long>(n * n * n);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }


    //calc lhs
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
      for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
          long res = arr[a] * arr[b] + arr[c];
          lhs.add(res);

          if (arr[c] != 0) {
            res = (arr[a] + arr[b]) * arr[c];
            rhs.add(res);
          }
        }
      }

    }

    //cal RHS

    Collections.sort(rhs);
    Collections.sort(lhs);

    int lIndex = 0, rIndex = 0;
    int res = 0;

    while (lIndex < lhs.size() && rIndex < rhs.size()) {
      if (lhs.get(lIndex).equals(rhs.get(rIndex))) {
        int lSize = 0;
        Long lEl = lhs.get(lIndex);
        int rSize = 0;
        Long rEl = rhs.get(rIndex);
        do {
          ++lSize;
          ++lIndex;
        } while (lIndex < lhs.size() && lhs.get(lIndex).equals(lEl));

        do {
          ++rSize;
          ++rIndex;
        } while (rIndex < rhs.size() && rhs.get(rIndex).equals(rEl));

        res += lSize * rSize;
      } else if (lhs.get(lIndex) < rhs.get(rIndex)) {
        ++lIndex;
      } else {
        ++rIndex;
      }
    }
out.println(res);

  }




}
```

What I am doing above is calculating all possible values for LHS and RHS of equation and counting the occurrence of each value of LHS in RHS.

I also tried only sorting the RHS array and doing binary search in it for finding the results, but the still the algorithm was not optimal enough to pass all the test cases.

Comment: According to [ask] and [mcve] posting a question about problem which is described on external service is `Unclear what you're asking`. This question not being described can't help anyone in the future.

Comment: Have Edited the question to include the complete problem statement.Thanks :)

Comment: It's enough to sort just one from {lhs, rhs}. The task is tagged `binarysearch`.

Comment: (This question is tagged brute-force.)

Comment: @xenteros, Yes I have tried that approach but that approach also gets TLE.

Comment: @greybeard On spoj it's binarysearch

Comment: I missed that you tried to transform the equation. Are you positive your form to be equivalent to _(a*b + c)/d - e = f_?

Comment: @greybeard: yes..just a algebraic transformation.

Comment: I suggest you copy the problem description as faithfully as possible from SPOJ _and make that evident using a block quote and an attribution_ (e.g. the hyperlink). Then, please show that transformation step-by-step.

Comment: If you look in the comments on the SPOJ page, it seems that whether the solution times out or not is very sensitive to implementation choices like whether to use a hash-based or tree-based map, or 32-bit or 64-bit numbers.  In your case, it might be something as stupid as the fact that (correct me if I'm wrong) Java's `ArrayList` will box and unbox each `Long`.

Comment: j_random_hacker already suggested to forgo `List<Long>` - I suggest at least trying `int[]`. Sorting the input set/array _may_ help sorting the LHSs/RHSs. To experiment with differently coded variants of counting identical values, I'd probably factor out a method (returning one more than the last index indexing the same value as the one passed in, incrementing one variable instead of two, galloping search, …). Using a multiset looks moot with a sort that shouldn't bog down with many identical keys - like dual pivot quicksort. Trying to exploit divisibility doesn't help with `1` as a value.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes its seems probable, I'had tried previously using int array but I was getting WA due to probably not handling the index well in rhs array. I'll try again will update with the result.